# load an object as values to ObjectChoiceField from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I can load an object as values into an `ObjectChoiceField` from a sqlite database. I need an example, I get the values of the database into a vector, but the drop-down list does not accept this type single array.

**clase BaseData**

```java
public Vector verSectores(){

    Vector v=new Vector();

    try{

        URI uri=URI.create("/SDCard/Databases/app/semana_calculadora.db");
        sqliteDB= DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
        Statement st= sqliteDB.createStatement("select Sector from sectores_app");
        st.prepare();
        Cursor c= st.getCursor();
        Row r; 

        while (c.next()){
            r=c.getRow();

            Sectores s= new Sectores(r.getString(0));

            v.addElement(s);
        }

        st.close();
        sqliteDB.close();

    }catch(Exception e){}
    return v;
}
```

**class Result**

```java
public class Resultados extends MainScreen{

private Vector v;

public Resultados(Vector v) {
    this.v = v;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {

        Sectores s=(Sectores)v.elementAt(i);

        //add(new LabelField(s.getName_sector()+ ""));
        add(new SeparatorField());
    }
}
```

as I have to pass the value of the vector to ObjectChoiceField?

**class Screen**

```java
comboFormato = new ObjectChoiceField("Format:", ********, 0){

    public void layout(int width, int height){

        width=350;

        super.layout(getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.layout(width, height);

        setExtent(width, super.getHeight());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        super.paint(g);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a Vector as the basis of an ObjectChoiceField, but you can use an array of Objects, and it is easy to convert a Vector to an array, using, for example, facilities provided by the Arrays class or just brute force as follows:

```
Sectores [] array = new Sectores [v.size()];
for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
  array[i] = (Sectores)v.elementAt(i);
}
```

Now you can provide 'array' to your ObjectChoiceField, but be aware the text that the ObjectChoiceField will display for each choice, will be the String generated by using each element's toString() method.

Comment: thanks for replying Peter, The method getSize () is undefined for the type Vector change it for size (), now the vector containing the sqlite query is in another different java file where I have the objectchoisefield, that's a problem? Referencing as

Comment: public Vector verSectores(){
  Vector v=new Vector();
  try{

   
   URI uri=URI.create("/SDCard/Databases/app/semana_calculadora.db");
   sqliteDB= DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
   Statement st= sqliteDB.createStatement("select Sector from sectores_app limit 3");
   st.prepare();
   Cursor c= st.getCursor();
   Row r; 
   while (c.next()){
    r=c.getRow();
    Sectores s= new Sectores(r.getString(0));

    v.addElement(s);   }

   st.close();
   sqliteDB.close();

  }catch(Exception e){}
  return v;
 }

Comment: @user2965942 - thanks for pointing out that getSize() is not valid - that will teach me to code from memory...  Code updated.  Re the code being in a different source - Sorry I don't understand your question.